There are times when I need to read man pages from a Windows machine. Is this possible?
When away from my Linux system I sometimes want to read up on a Linux command. Today it is xrandr. The online web sources do not seem to have it. Any ideas?

If you're after Ubuntu man pages, they are available online..
eg.   for 24.10 you can view
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oracular/man1/xrandr.1.html
They also provide the manual pages for specific releases, as they can differ, ie. the URL I provided shows the 24.10 or oracular release page, but you can change the keyword or click a release to change release.

Stopped my search just a moment too soon
https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/xrandr.1.html
